# SE website recently doesn't work properly

Tags: support

Recent days I observe unpleasant behavior of SE website. At submitting of answer or comment it says "an error happens ...". Also including images make the some problems. In all cases the second try is successful (yet). I also observe, that after this sometimes the question and answer disappear for while (about 10 minutes) from list of top questions.

Does anyone experienced this? To whom I should report this problems? It seems that meta-TeX is not right place to report such website technical issues.

Comment: ...it probably isn't. If the problem is generic to the Stack Exchange network, then a post on [meta.se] would be the way to go. Regardless, and similar to how we typically request some form of MWE, one would require information to replicate the problem in order to adequately address it.

Comment: So far, i did *not* experience this behaviour. Everything working as usual.

Comment: @Werner, thank you for information. I'm not sure, if the problem is in webpage or in my OS (Windows 10). I'm quit disappointed on it.

Comment: I see this problem at times, but not continually. GNU/Linux Firefox. I am not disappointed in my OS or Firefox, so I'm assuming a problem on SE's side. Usually, it happens randomly for some question or two, and then it resolves again.

Comment: I can confirm this too, occasionally it happens (also Linux/Firefox) or particular long loading times of the site itself.

Comment: I too can confirm this too - also errors when trying to vote on questions.  The site is not as stable as it used to be.